# Read message and subject from Gmail email and write to Google Sheets with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to save subject and message to Sheets, but I got an error:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getSubject" of undefined.

Here is my code:

```
    var archivoStock ="(key of the sheet)";

function myFunction() {
  //Bucar el excel - Search in the sheet
   var file = DriveApp.searchFiles(archivoStock);
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(archivoStock);
   var hoja = sheet.getSheets()[0];
  //Cargar los correros en la bandeja de entrada - Charge the mail in the inbox
  var bandeja = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  for(var i=0; i < 2;i++)
  {
    var mensaje = bandeja[i].getMessages()[i];
    //Logger.log("Mensaje "+ mensaje.getBody());
    //Rellenar una celda - add content to the celd
    hoja.getRange(1,1).setValue(mensaje.getSubject());
   hoja.getRange(1,2).setValue(mensaje.getBody())
    hoja.getRange(1,3).setValue(bandeja.length)    

    //Logger.log("Asunto "+ asunto);
  }
  //Leer los archivos - Read the file  
   //Logger.log("archivo "+ sheet.getName());
  //Browser.msgBox("Leyendo excel "+ sheet.getName());

}
```

Why I got this error?

Comment: I'd guess that some of the threads don't have  more than one message.  Do you really want the second index in here? `var message = threads[i].getm.getMessages()[i];` Perhaps it would be better to have a second loop.

Comment: I read the documentation and I think that the threads[i] are de mail. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getSubject" of undefined.

Answer:

> You are calling for undefined value, index which doesn't exist

If you have `getMessageCount()` more than 1, I would suggest you to create another for loop inside, something like this

```js
function getMessages(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  var messages = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {

    // thread(mail) id
    Logger.log("Thread ID: " + threads[i].getId())

    // first subject
    Logger.log("Subject: " + threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject())

    // how many messages are in thread
    Logger.log("Messages: " + Number(threads[i].getMessageCount()))

    for(var j = 0; j < Number(threads[i].getMessageCount()); j++){
      Logger.log("Message " + j + " : " + threads[i].getMessages()[j].getPlainBody())
      messages.push(threads[i].getMessages()[j].getPlainBody())      
    }

    Logger.log("________________________________________________")

  }

  Logger.log(messages)
//  sheet.getRange(j+1, 1).setValue(threads[i].getMessages()[j].getPlainBody());

}
```

and after you can use `messages[]` how ever you want, `sheet.getRange(x,x).setValue(messages[x])` f.e.

### References

- [Gmail Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail)
- [GmailThread](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread)

Comment: Thanks, this works. I read the reference before but i think that threads[i] are the mail not inside with  threads[i].getMessages()[j] . I need more improve my english